# Pandas expand multiple columns with list

Tags: pandas

Input

```
         col           ts
row     
65536   [592]         [2019-04-24 22:33:11]
65537   [576, 592]    [2019-04-25 04:37:13, 2019-04-25 04:37:14]
65538   [592]         [2019-04-25 04:37:13]
65539   [576, 592]    [2019-04-25 01:33:49, 2019-04-25 01:33:49]
65540   [592]         [2019-04-25 01:33:49]
```

I need a transformation to make the output as

```
         col           ts
row     
65536    592           2019-04-24 22:33:11
65537    576           2019-04-25 04:37:13
65537    592           2019-04-25 04:37:14
65538    592           2019-04-25 04:37:13
65539    576           2019-04-25 01:33:49
65539    592           2019-04-25 01:33:49
65540    592           2019-04-25 01:33:49
```

In every row, `col` has a list that has the same length with a list in `ts`

Comment: Try this out ```list_cols = {'col','ts'}
exploded = [df[col].explode() for col in list_cols]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list_cols, exploded)))```

Comment: You are looking for this: df.set_index(['row']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()